# Perl while loop with a regex condition, does not seem to re-enter the loop

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to read a `diff` file, and group the delete hunks (with leading `-<SPACE>`) and add hunks (leading `+<SPACE>`), I have the following, where I want to have an inner `while` to read all the deletes, or adds, but somehow I see that after the first match, the loop doesn't seem to *re-evaluate*, i.e after a line matches the condition on line `32`, it enters the loop and then I read another line into `$_` but the control transfers out of the loop to line `36` instead of re-entering the loop and check the condition again! (I checked from the debugger)

```
 27 while (<$inh>) {
 28     next if /^$/;   
 29     next if /^[^-+]/;         # ignore non diff lines 
 30     chomp;
 31     my $tmps = '';
 32     while (/^\-\ /) {         # Read the entire block (all lines beginning with -<SPACE>
 33         $tmps .= getprintables($_);
 34         $_ = <$inh>;          # Read next line
 35     }
 36     push(@prevs, $tmps) if $tmps ne '';
 37     $tmps = '';
 38     while (/^\+\ /) {         # Read the entire block (all lines beginning with +<SPACE>
 39         $tmps .= getprintables($_);
 40         $_ = <$inh>;
 41     }
 42     push(@curs, $tmps) if $tmps ne '';
 43     $tmps = '';
 44 }
 45 close($inh);
```

I also tried the longer form `while ($_ =~ m/^\+\ /)` but same results. I don't see what is wrong here. I have `Perl v5.14.2`

Comment: @Miller, If I wanted to match more than once on the same line, then I would need `/g`, but here I want to match on a different line altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest only ever doing your reading from a file handle from a single while loop, and using state variables to perform additional logic.

If I'm reading your intent properly, you can redesign your approach to use the [Range operator `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) instead like so:

```
while (<$inh>) {
    next if /^$/;
    next if /^[^-+]/;    # ignore non diff lines
    chomp;

    if ( my $range = /^- / .. !/^- / ) {
        push @prevs, '' if $range == 1;
        $prevs[-1] .= getprintables($_) if $range !~ /E/;
    }

    if ( my $range = /^\+ / .. !/^\+ / ) {
        push @curs, '' if $range == 1;
        $curs[-1] .= getprintables($_) if $range !~ /E/;
    }
}

close($inh);
```

Comment: I can re-write the loop to make sure to read only once from file handle (but, does it cause any prob if we re-read?). I've used range in `sed`, but this one stumped me!,I tried this, and it didn't seem to read the entire block.

Comment: ok, now after trying some examples of range, I am getting the logic, will re-work.